# Is there a way to implement a builder pattern with a "restrictive API" without being too verbose

Tags: java, architecture, builder

When working on the design of a component `X`'s , I'd like to use a builder pattern that allows to specify the `A`, `B` and `C` values in a fluent fashion for usability purposes.

For similar usability purpose, I'd like to make so that it's not possible (API-wise) for ANY developer using X's API to specify `A`,`B` or `C` more than once.

However, I cannot accept a runtime-failure of the builder due to the time cost of the feedback for the API user, and allowing the value to be overridden by the second call makes no sense functionally, so it cannot be accepted either.

The only solution I have found for this issue would be to create 8(!) builder interfaces, each with their own implementation for such a builder :

```
IHaveNothing<X>
IHaveA<X>
IHaveB<X>
IHaveC<X>
IHaveAAndB<X>
IHaveAAndC<X>
IHaveBAndC<X>
IHaveAAndBAndC<X>
```

This is a bit overkill for such a simple builder, but couldn't think of anything less verbose than that.

Is there any pattern that would alleviate the verbosity of such a builder ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you enforce some ordering of the elements, you can get away with less interfaces. By doing that, you don't need to have interfaces for all of A+B, A+C and B+C.

Another trick is to only create 1 builder implementation class that implements all the interfaces, which can be inaccessible to the API-user.

Something like this:

```
interface ResultBuilder {
    static ABuilder builder() {
        return new ResultBuilderImpl();
    }

    interface ABuilder {
        BBuilder a(A a);
    }

    interface BBuilder {
        CBuilder b(B b);
    }

    interface CBuilder {
        ResultBuilder c(C c);
    }

    Result build();
}
```

And the implementation:

```
class ResultBuilderImpl implements ResultBuilder, 
                                   ResultBuilder.ABuilder, 
                                   ResultBuilder.BBuilder, 
                                   ResultBuilder.CBuilder {
    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;

    public BBuilder a(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        return this;
    }

    public CBuilder b(B b) {
        this.b = b;
        return this;
    }

    public ResultBuilder c(C c) {
        this.c = c;
        return this;
    }

    public Result build() {
        return new Result(a, b, c);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
Result result = ResultBuilder.builder()
    .a(new A())
    .b(new B())
    .c(new C())
    .build();
```

Comment: You can do it without restrict the parameter order (see my response).

Comment: @josejuan Sure, but it becomes a lot more complex. I think enforcing ordering is a pragmatic tradeoff. It will also make the usage of the builder a bit easier to read, because you always get the properties in the same predicable order.

Comment: a lot more complex is, for sure, the user must to know the only one valid combination between `n!` possibles (as you solution require). My solution have a tradeoff respect yours to be `O(n^2)` code size (instead `O(n)` of your solution). But if you are referring to the complexity of understanding my solution, it is not at all if you put a little effort into it.

Answer (score 1):

Java have not backtracking when resolve types (have not complex type inference) but you can construct a builder without restrict to set values in an especific order.

Define types to annotate when a parameter is settled:

```
interface A {}
interface B {}
interface C {}
```

Define types to annotate when a parameter is not settled:

```
interface NA {}
interface NB {}
interface NC {}
```

The builder looks like as:

```
static class Builder<R, S, T> {
    int _a = 0;
    int _b = 0;
    int _c = 0;
    R r;
    S s;
    T t;
    Builder(int _a, int _b, int _c, R r, S s, T t) {
        this._a = _a;
        this._b = _b;
        this._c = _c;
        this.r = r;
        this.s = s;
        this.t = t;
    }
    static <R extends NA, S, T> Builder<A, S, T> A(Builder<R, S, T> z, int n) {
        return new Builder<>(n, z._b, z._c, null, null, null);
    }
    static <R, S extends NB, T> Builder<R, B, T> B(Builder<R, S, T> z, int n) {
        return new Builder<>(z._a, n, z._c, null, null, null);
    }
    static <R, S, T extends NC> Builder<R, S, C> C(Builder<R, S, T> z, int n) {
        return new Builder<>(z._a, z._b, n, null, null, null);
    }
    static Builder<NA, NB, NC> builder() {
        return new Builder<>(0, 0, 0, null, null, null);
    }
    <M, N> M set(BiFunction<Builder<? extends R, ? extends S, ? extends T>, N, M> k, N n) {
        return k.apply(this, n);
    }
    void build() {
        System.out.printf("<%d, %d, %d>%n", _a, _b, _c);
    }
}
```

when:

1. `_a`, `_b`, ... is every typed parameter.
2. `r`, `s`, ... is the type annotation to carry out when is or not settled.
3. the constructor.
4. `A`, `B`, ... is the static restriction transforming a non settled annotation to a settled annotation.
5. `builder` construct the non settled initial value.
6. `set` do the magic, enabling backtracking in type annotations.
7. `build` in this case print values.

Now we can set values in any order

```
builder().set(Builder::B, 2).set(Builder::A, 1).build();
builder().set(Builder::A, 1).set(Builder::C, 3).set(Builder::B, 2).build();
```

with output

```
<1, 2, 0>
<1, 2, 3>
```

but if you try to set twice

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could implement a class or interface per step and allow to create `X` at each step. Something like this:

```
class X {  }

interface BuildStep {
    X build();          
}

interface StepC extends BuildStep {
    BuildStep c(String param);
}

interface StepB extends StepC {
    StepC b(String param);
}

interface StepA extends StepB {
    StepB a(String param);
}

class XBuilder implements StepA {

    @Override
    public StepC b(String param) {  
        //handle param
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public BuildStep c(String param) {
        //handle param
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public StepB a(String param) {
        //handle param
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public X build() {
        //build the new X
        return new X();
    }
    
    static XBuilder builder() {
        return new XBuilder ();
    }
}
```

That way your cases would look like this (order of calls would be enforced, i.e. A -> B -> C -> X, while being able to start anywhere in that chain):

```
X x;

//IHaveNothing<X>
x = XBuilder.builder().build();

//IHaveA<X>
x = XBuilder.builder().a(param).build();

//IHaveB<X>
x = XBuilder.builder().b(param).build();

//IHaveC<X>
x = XBuilder.builder().c(param).build();

//IHaveAAndB<X>
x = XBuilder.builder().a(param).b(param).build();

//IHaveAAndC<X>
x = XBuilder.builder().a(param).c(param).build();

//IHaveBAndC<X>
x = XBuilder.builder().b(param).c(param).build();

//IHaveAAndBAndC<X>
x = XBuilder.builder().a(param).b(param).c(param).build();
```

This, however, wouldn't be allowed:

```
//those make the compiler cry and slap you in the face :)
x = XBuilder.builder().c(param).a(param).b(param).build();
x = XBuilder.builder().a(param).a(param).b(param).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

IHaveNothing with ProvideA(...) only

IHaveA with ProvideB(...) only

IHaveAB with ProvideC(...) only

IHaveABC with Build() only

should be enough or did I not understood your requirements to the full extend? that design forces an order though.